# Setting Up VPN Practice/Service Without Access to Private Internet

Tags: linux, encryption, vpn

I use Lubuntu 14.04.

I've gotten concerned about encrypting my internet traffic after reading about the problems with public WiFi and intend to start using VPN.

However, all my internet usage is on public WiFi because I have no private internet access. What's either a good practice or good free service given this limitation?

I'm confused about OpenVPN. It sounds good, but unless I misunderstand, it's only for private internet connections, right? It says something about establishing a server, which I assume I can't do since I don't have my own server hardware.

However, if I can set up all the web encryption I'd ever need on my laptop alone,then I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and direct answer, you can't.

Detailed response for what is necessary:

I don't know what you mean by private internet.  But you appear to elude to the limitations you probably have that might prevent you from setting up a VPN server (private network... not private internet).

To setup a virtual private network you'll need a public (static) IP for your machines to connect to.  Once they connect to this public IP of your server, it will provide routing to the machines for a virtual private network which would resemble having a private network separate from the Internet.

There are two popular packages available for Linux and that includes the OpenVPN which you referenced and PPTP.

Your first step to setting up your VPN resolution would be to get your public (static) ip, then proceed with your preference of the two popular packages.

By the way, I put static in parenthesis because while it's expected and better to have a static ip (an ip that doesn't change), a dynamic IP could suffice.  However, you would have to notify the machines of the new public IP every time it changes.

The main key is having a public ip for your client machines to all connect to.

Comment: By private internet I made I don't have a service I pay for. The only internet I use is from the library, Starbucks, etc. Would OpenVPN and PPTP work with those? At this point is looks like only VPN services are available to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to get into setting up a VPN server, but I will go over the absolute minimum that you should know about VPN use with public WiFi.

A VPN connection (for your purposes) is simply a protected connection between your computer and another computer/server. When you connect to the Internet via public WiFi, you should be most concerned with your data as it travels from your computer to the hotspot/router. The VPN just bridges the gap between your computer on an unsafe WiFi hotspot and the presumably safer Internet connection afforded to the VPN server. A VPN will not protect your data anywhere else along it's journey to the remote host/website. Unless used in combination with other services/tools (i.e. DNSSEC, SSL, Tor) your data is still very vulnerable to interception or manipulation by nefarious entities along undersea cables, at malicious endpoints, while at rest, etc.

So as you see, it would make no sense to setup a VPN server behind public WiFi... All of the VPN's traffic would still be unprotected, making the connection for users slower and even more vulnerable.

In your situation, the best advice would be to look into a private VPN service that you can trust. I don't have any specific recommendations, but I personally would prefer a service that accepted payment via cryptocurrency and was in a suitable political climate (i.e. another country).

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you. I am aware that my data is essentially leaving its fate to the wind given that I can't affect how the data travels beyond my computer, but I would like to do all I can on my side. I'll keep an eye out for VPN services, though they're tough to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking or perhaps an anonymous [VPN](https://www.fipe.net/) want to maintain your real IP hidden, as well as your identity online a secret, you are probably wondering should they truly help keep you anonymous, or if it's just for real. There are naturally, several security features to take a look out for - security features which can be standard, and a few that happen to be upgrades that only a few VPN services offer. Keeping user logs is an interesting issue amongst the privacy policy pages of some VPN services, where there were several cases earlier this year which made some users question the anonymity of certain VPN services.